# Java Programming Exercise "From Parameter to One"

Tags: methods, while-loop, printing, parameters, break

I'm new to Java and all things programming so I will explain this the best I can.

I'm trying to create a simple program that includes a method that calls on a parameter to print a sequence of descending numbers. This numerical sequence starts at a number given by the user and stops at 1.

The assignment is as follows:
*Create the following method in the exercise template: public static void printFromNumberToOne(int number). It should print the numbers from the number passed as a parameter down to one.*

e.g.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printFromNumberToOne(5);

sample output:
5
4
3
2
1

When I run the program I have written so far to solve the exercise, it starts at 5, and descends beyond 1 indefinitely into negative integers (5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,∞...)

I need to insert a break or the condition that the loop stops running once i=0, but I have no idea how to do this without getting an error message. Where am I going wrong?

here's the method parameter in question:

```
public static void printFromNumbertoOne(int num) {
    int i = 5;
    while (i <= num) {
        System.out.println(i--);
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: The loop stop condition is `i<=num` which is always true. Try start i with num, `int i=num`, and change while condition to `i>0`.

Comment: This simple solution was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a `while` loop will continue running as long as it's condition (`i <= num` in your case) is `true`. With `i--` you are decreasing `i` on every run of the loop and since `i` starts at 5 and `num` is also 5 in your example, `i <= num` is always `true` and your loop will run forever.

I would recommend to use `while (num > 0)` instead and change the next line to `System.out.println(num--);`. Thereby the loop would run as long as `num` is bigger than 0 and `num` is being decreased on every loop run.

<strike>Please be aware that this version would still run forever if you start the function with a negative value as in `printFromNumbertoOne(-5);`. To handle that you should also include a check whether `num` is positive.</strike>

**Edit:** I'm sorry, I was a bit tired yesterday. It would not actually run forever, instead the loop `while (num > 0)` would just not run when `num` is negative or 0, since the condition would never be `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer makes sense except I don't understand how I would "include a check on whether num is positive". I imagine this would need one more line of code added such as ' if (num>0) '... but where would that fit?

Comment: The check is actually not necessary, see my edit of the answer. Sorry.